# Is a one off request/case possible to have a Full Sandbox 29 day wait waived?

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh, salesforce-support

We have a very important data migration coming up and I'd really rather not wait the full 29 day waiting period that Salesforce implements for a Full sandbox.

Has anyone opened a request with Salesforce? Is this even possible? Any escalation tips or "secret verbiage" we can use on Case to make it happen?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is *possible* to request a waiver for the 29 day refresh. From the last time I heard about this, you cannot refresh earlier than 2 days since the last refresh (system enforced limit), you must have a valid business reason, and, short of needing to refresh because of Salesforce system errors, you only get one. Consider carefully if you really want to waste your one request on this project. We recently purchased a second full sandbox just so we could refresh effectively every 15 days.